# Why is Pyspark so much slower on Windows than on Linux?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Okay, so I'm new to Apache Spark, and I tried running some basic scripts with Python to see what it's like. Right now I'm trying the following Python script that uses Pyspark to count the instances that a certain word (in this example, the word "word") appears in a bunch of Python files in a directory:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys
import os

def get_files(path):
    ls = ''
    for i in os.walk(path):
        directory, ls_files = i[0], i[2]
        for file in ls_files:
            if file.endswith('.py') and not file.startswith('_'):
                path = os.path.join(directory, file)
                ls += path
                ls += ','
    return ls[0:-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('This program only accpets one argument as input.')
    else:
        files = get_files(sys.argv[1])
        sc = SparkContext()
        num = sc.textFile(files).flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')).filter(lambda x: 'word' in x).count()
        print(f'********* \'word\' appears {num} times')
```

As you can see, I'm using all of the default options for SparkConf.

Well, if I try running this simple program with Windows, passing as an argument a folder with around 10MB, and 460 .py files, it takes around 3 minutes. On the same computer, I try exactly the same thing, with the same folder, using Ubuntu, and it literally takes 3 seconds.

How can such a strong difference in times be explained? I can understand that maybe some of these programs are better designed for Unix systems, but at the end of the day, it's the same processor, running multiple tasks in parallel across all 8 cores, so it doesn't really make a lot of sense to me that it works so slow on Windows.

Comment: It's not just pyspark, python was (I haven't tested it lately) also slower on windows.  A couple years ago when I tested this, Python on windows subsystem linux was much faster than native windows.

Comment: How is the Spark cluster you connect to configured? Does it have the same configuration on both systems? Which processes are taking up CPU on the Windows box when you run this?

Comment: @J'e File operations and process creation can be notably slower on Windows, but I don't think WSL Python is all-round faster than native Windows Python unless I see evidence :)

Comment: @AKX, google it! I did say this was a couple years ago. It may not be an issue any more. https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/6qndr6/why_is_python_50_faster_under_windows_subsystem/

Comment: @J'e Mm, fair enough - MSVC not supporting computed gotos is likely a culprit :) I suppose things may have evened out if MSVC has learned new tricks in the meanwhile...